# How to substitute values in tensorflow array

Tags: tensorflow

I have an input_array of dimension (70000, 1) type integer. E.g. first 10 values

```
[[1]
 [9]
 [2]
 [10]
 [2]
 [5]
 [10]
 [3]
 [3]
 [10]]
```

I want to replace all the occurrences of 10 with 0 in the second axis. What is the best way to do this in tensorflow ? While doing

tf.map_fn(fn=lambda t: tf.math.mod(t, 10), elems=input_array)
gives me

```
NotFoundError: Could not find valid device for node.
Node:{{node FloorMod}}
All kernels registered for op FloorMod :
  device='XLA_CPU'; T in [DT_FLOAT, DT_DOUBLE, DT_INT32, DT_INT64, DT_BFLOAT16, DT_HALF]
  device='XLA_CPU_JIT'; T in [DT_FLOAT, DT_DOUBLE, DT_INT32, DT_INT64, DT_BFLOAT16, DT_HALF]
  device='CPU'; T in [DT_DOUBLE]
  device='CPU'; T in [DT_FLOAT]
  device='CPU'; T in [DT_INT64]
  device='CPU'; T in [DT_INT32]
 [Op:FloorMod]
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

See [tf.where](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/where) command. In your case:

```
tf.where(condition=tf.math.equal(t, 10), x=0, y=t)
```